# Integrating Facebook SDK in Windows 8 JS application

Tags: javascript, windows, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to develop a Windows 8 app and I want to integrate Facebook in it.
I know this can be done without their SDK, but I've seen it can also be done with it and I'd love to go for the SDK.

I have the all.js file downloaded and referenced.

I included the initialization code in default.html:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
            appId: '*******',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
            status: true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
            xfbml: true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
        });

        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    };
</script>
```

I'm trying to login using `FB.login()` when a button is pressed, but it's not working because

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                console.log("entered")
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    console.log("connected");

                } else {
                    console.log("connecting");
                    FB.login(function (response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            console.log("connected");
                        } else {
                            console.log("canceled");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

However, nothing happens when I click the button I attached this function to.
What can it be?
Any help is appreciated,
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login  Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
    alert("hh");
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '197393374008468',

    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.7' // use version 2.2
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the  SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the  SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```